# Is recombination and quantum dissipation the same?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, open-quantum-systems

I have been reading two articles on the quantum transport in the FMO complex [1]. Each of these papers models a different processes that affects the quantum transport of the excitons in the FMO complex. The first article describes something known as quantum dissipation. However, I haven't seen any other paper discussing this process in their model. I have, however seen recombination in similar models. Another thing that might hint to this is that their equation that includes quantum dissipation is very similar to the typical Lindblad equation used for modeling the FMO complex, however is augmented by an extra term. So, is there a difference? If so, why is this process important for the FMO complex transport?

[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.4688 and https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.0929

Comment: It would really help if you can include the equations you're mentioning so the reader doesn't have to go read two entire journal articles in order to understand your question :)